# How to display image in email using action mailer in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a application for sending mail to users, for that I am using action mailer in my application. 
I want show a image in mail but I am not able to do this.Can anyone help in how to make it possible.
I am using paper clip gem for storing images in my application.
Field in database storing image name like

prescription_file_name =>  "foo_bar_thumbnail_image7.jpg"
but the actually complete URL for that image is like

```
"/system/service_requests/prescriptions/000/000/237/medium/foo_bar_thumbnail_image7.jpg?1455861395".
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does a simple [`image_tag`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view) like `<%= image_tag @object.image_name.url %>` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a complete web url in emails to display images

```
"/system/service_requests/prescriptions/000/000/237/medium/foo_bar_thumbnail_image7.jpg?1455861395".
This won't work. Its a path only known to your server.
```

So you need to have it like this(complete url):

```
"http://www.example.com/system/service_requests/prescriptions/000/000/237/medium/foo_bar_thumbnail_image7.jpg?1455861395".

Here http://www.example.com is your domain.
```

**If image is stored into app's public directory, Use this:**

```
Rails.root.join(@object.image_name.url)
```

**If image is stored somewhere else like S3, Use this:**

```
@object.image_name.url
```

**PS: This image should be publicly accessible.**

Comment: Not able to find the solution as I am tring like that                                                      imgurl = "https://www.example.com" + @service_requests.prescription.url 
<img src="#{imgurl}">                                                                                               Can you help me to find out the solution for that

Answer (score 2):

You should try this in your mailer.rb

```
attachments['image.jpg'] = File.read(@photo.prescription_file.path(:original))
```

@photo is contained the details of the image

then in the email view file

```
<%= image_tag attachments['image.jpg'].url %>
```

add this.. it works perfectly for me.